# Java - JSON De-/Serializer without Reflection

Tags: java, json, proguard, compile-time, serialization

I'm looking for a JSON de-/serializer in Java that is not based on reflection but that generates the serializer code at compile-time.

I already had a look at [zappos-json](https://github.com/Zappos/zappos-json) but it performs the code generation at runtime.

Background:
*I got a Java application obfuscated with ProGuard. Originally Jackson was doing the de-/serailization of Java objects from/to json but due to the identifier obfuscation it not longer works. Instead of excluding the affected Java classes from obfuscation I would like to generate the necessary de-/serialization code at compile-time where the identifiers are still available.*

Comment: Just write the code yourself. Or don't use an obfuscator - they're pointless and cause more harm than good.

Comment: It is called LoganSquare, and I am surprised, that you had so much trouble looking for it. It is easily google-able.